# Proxy_pass vs Fastcgi_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, php-fpm, fastcgi, proxypass

With one server/container on with nginx and another one with fpm, is it better to fastcgi_pass from the nginx to the fpm or proxy_pass to the fpm with addional installtion of nginx on the fpm? Both methods can load balance right? In that case does't the first method have less overhead of an additional server?

Comment: Why would you want to add an extra bit if you don't actually need it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton By extra bit, do you mean the nginx on the fpm server? In that case is proxy_pass only needed if case we need reverse proxy to a pre-existing apache backend?

Comment: Yes, the extra nginx is unnecessary and so is the extra apache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Just one last query, since in fastcgi_pass both servers need to have the files to serve, is it better to (automated) copy files to both servers or have the files to a networked drive connected to both servers

Comment: What is the difference between proxy-pass-and-fastcgi-pass?

Comment: Related: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2295464-proxy_pass-vs-fastcgi_pass-for-nginx-php-fpm